# RefTeX reftex-citation not showing all entries and takes preceding word as argument

Tags: auctex, completion, markdown-mode, reftex-mode, citation

After initial setting up emacs with AuCTeX and RefTeX everything worked fine.

---

*may not be the problem, see **edit** below*

Now, for a porject I tried setting up RefTeX to work with `markdown-mode` with this [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/kleinschmidt/5ab0d3c423a7ee013a2c01b3919b009a). Since these changes my RefTeX seems not be working correct anymore. First I tried it in a markdown file. Emacs asked me to `SELECT A CITATION FORMAT` and then shows:

```
[^M] [@%l]
[p] [@%l]
[t] @%l
```

after that, in the minibuffer the line `Regex { && Regex...}:` appears, but followed by the previous word of the md file in brackets `[word]:`. If I then try to search for a bib-key, it says `[no match]`. When I hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> without any character, it inserts the preceding word in brackets. If I then hit enter, it only shows a few (6-8) entries from my bib file which in reality contains hundreds of entries.

So I removed the code from my `init.el`. But the problem persists.

---

Even if I try to enter a citation with `C-c [` (or running `M-x reftex-citation`) from a `.tex` file, emacs now asks me to `SELECT A CITATION FORMAT` with a list beginning with `[^M] \cite[][]{%l}` followed by author `biblatex` citation commands. Thats even weirder since I've not enabled `biblatex` in the `reftex-cite-format` variable:

[image]

Plus, the problem remains the same: RefTeX inserts the preceding word in brackets, only allows to autocomplete to this word in particular and then shows very few random entries from my bibfile.

In the following with this short MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{~/path/to/my.bib}

\begin{document}
Test
% <here try to enter citation with C-c [ >
\end{document}
```

After the `SELECT A CITATION FORMAT`, which I skipped by predding <kbd>RET</kbd> for the default value, the `Regex` line appears with the preceding word `Text` in bracktes:

[image]

I only can choose this particular word with <kbd>TAB</kbd> completion:

[image]

If I hit <kbd>RET</kbd>, only a very small number of entries appear:

[image]

I also tried to remove all `reftex` code from the `init.el` and reset every reftex variable to the default value (I didn't edit many, only `reftex-default-bibliography` manually).

*But the problem persists*

Since I'm relativley new to emacs, I have no idea what the problem is. Did the settings for markdown changed some core values of RefTeX?

**Edit**

I even tried to remove emacs completley, as well as the `.emacs.d` folder and reinstall it. But nothing changed. I also tried it at my companies laptop which is running Windows. But the behaviour is the same. Maybe I'm doing something really wrong... Any ideas??

Starting emacs without init `emacs --no-init-file` results in the same...

Answer (score 0):

Reg. your first question:

> emacs now asks me to SELECT A CITATION FORMAT with a list beginning
> with `[^M] \cite[][]{%l}` followed by author `biblatex` citation
> commands. Thats even weirder since I've not enabled `biblatex` in the
> `reftex-cite-format` variable

I presume that you're using AUCTeX as well.  In this case, AUCTeX loads its support file `biblatex.el` which has this line:

```el
(reftex-set-cite-format 'biblatex)
```

Docstring says:

> Set the document-local value of `reftex-cite-format`. When such a
> value exists, it overwrites the setting given with
> `reftex-cite-format`.  See the documentation of `reftex-cite-format`
> for possible values.  This function should be used from AUCTeX style
> files.

Reg. your second question:

> After the `SELECT A CITATION FORMAT`, which I skipped by predding `R`ET
> for the default value, the `Regex` line appears with the preceding word
> `Text` in bracktes:

RefTeX just looks back and tries to find something which could make sense, in this case `Text`: If you hit `RET`, you accept it, otherwise you enter your search regexp.

This is from RefTeX manual for `reftex-citation`:

> The regular expression uses an expanded syntax: `&&` is interpreted as
> `and`. Thus, `aaaa&&bbb` matches entries which contain both `aaaa` and
> `bbb`. While entering the regexp, completion on knows citation keys is
> possible. `=` is a good regular expression to match all entries in all
> files.

So the question is why completion doesn't work for you.